# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol " " when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ; not null range default character

Tags: oracle, plsql

Why doesn't this work?
Any advice or solutions are greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OverReading
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON MeterReadings
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    emp_counter INTEGER;
    max_meter INTEGER : = 5;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(EmployeeId) INTO emp_counter
    FROM MeterReadings 
    WHERE EmployeeId = :NEW.EmployeeId;
IF : OLD.EmployeeId = NEW.EmployeeId THEN
    RETURN;
ELSIF emp_counter >= max_meter THEN
    raise_application_error(-20900,'Employee are limited to a maximum of 5 meters');
END IF;
END;
/
```

The Error that is thrown to me
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three syntax errors, all of them related to `:` character.

When fixed, trigger compiles:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER OverReading
  2      BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON MeterReadings
  3      FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5      emp_counter INTEGER;
  6      max_meter INTEGER := 5;                       --> here
  7  BEGIN
  8      SELECT COUNT(EmployeeId) INTO emp_counter
  9      FROM MeterReadings
 10      WHERE EmployeeId = :NEW.EmployeeId;
 11  IF :OLD.EmployeeId = :NEW.EmployeeId THEN        --> 2x here
 12      RETURN;
 13  ELSIF emp_counter >= max_meter THEN
 14      raise_application_error(-20900,'Employee are limited to a maximum of 5 meters');
 15  END IF;
 16  END;
 17  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

**However**: this code will run if you insert rows one-by-one. Otherwise, it will raise **mutating table error** as you're selecting from the same table you're inserting into (which is not allowed). If that bothers you, there are ways to fix it. Depending on database version you use, it could be a compound trigger or a type + package option.